# How to POST JSON + pdf file with Unirest in NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, unirest

In NodeJS I am trying to POST JSON data to the server along with a file using the following code:

```
unirest.post(url)
.headers(headers)
.send(data)
.attach('file', file)
.end(function (response) {
    var statusCode = response.status;
    if (statusCode != 200) {
        console.log("Result: ", response.error);
    }
});
```

However, on the server, I am only receiving the file, and not the JSON object from `.send(data)`. I see there is a `.multipart()` function I can use, but I'm not sure how best to use this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send JSON data over http, content type is `application/json`. when you send files over http, content type is `multipart/form-data`. You can send form fields while sending a multipart request but you can't send JSON data in multipart request. You have 2 options to send this request

1. While using `multipart/form-data`, Stringify you JSON data and send it as a form field and parse it on other end
2. While using `application/json`, Base64 you file and send it as a property in your JSON data